# symbolic link for libevent not being found when installing memcached

Tags: linux, unix, memcached, symlink

After installing memcached and trying to run using the memached command I receive this error :

```
memcached: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After googling I found this : http://www.nigeldunn.com/2011/12/11/libevent-2-0-so-5-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/ which suggest to add a symbolic link : `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5 /usr/lib64/libevent-2.0.so.5` but I receive same error.

What else can I try ?

Comment: Where `libevent-2.0.so.5` is located ? Are you sure `/usr/local/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5` exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just re-created the symbolic link and it seems to work fine. Only thing I can think of is that perhaps I originally created the link logged in as non root.